# UpdatePanel not updating ListBox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, listbox, updatepanel

I have an UpdatePanel containing a ListBox. Whenever I change selection on from a DropDown I want the list to get updated via an UpdatePanel. However this is not working.

This is my code so far:

```
 Protected Sub drpDepartments_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles drpDepartments.SelectedIndexChanged

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim deptComm As String = "SELECT department_id FROM departments WHERE department_name = @DepartmentName"

        Dim deptSQL As New SqlCommand
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = deptSQL.ExecuteReader()

        deptSQL = New SqlCommand(deptComm, conn)
        deptSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentName", drpDepartments.SelectedItem.Text)

        dr.Read()

        If dr.HasRows Then


            Dim department_id As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(dr("department_id"))
            Session("DepartmentID") = department_id

        End If

        dr.Close()
        conn.Close()
```

ASP

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:ListBox ID="lstDeptMembers" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="name" Height="176px" Width="204px"></asp:ListBox>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drpDepartments" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStringDb1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM users u
INNER JOIN 
(
Select x.user_id as userid,x.department_id,y.department_name
 from user_Department x 
inner join departments y 
on x.department_id=y.department_id WHERE x.department_id=@parameter
) 
    f on u.user_id= f.userid">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:SessionParameter Name="parameter" SessionField="DepartmentID" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

DropDownList:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="drpDepartments" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="department_name" DataValueField="department_name">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStringDb1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [department_name] FROM [departments]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

How can I make it that the ListBox updates whenever a new selection is clicked from the DropDown ?

**EDIT:** Code for the table that contains the ListBox etc.. :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpDepartments" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="department_name" DataValueField="department_name">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStringDb1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [department_name] FROM [departments]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <br />

    <br />


     <table style="width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 221px">






                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:ListBox ID="lstDeptMembers" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="name" Height="176px" Width="204px"></asp:ListBox>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drpDepartments" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>

                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStringDb1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM users u
    INNER JOIN 
    (
    Select x.user_id as userid,x.department_id,y.department_name
     from user_Department x 
    inner join departments y 
    on x.department_id=y.department_id WHERE x.department_id=@parameter
    ) 
        f on u.user_id= f.userid">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:SessionParameter Name="parameter" SessionField="DepartmentID" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>

                </td>
                <td style="width: 398px">


                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtuserSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSearchDeptUser" runat="server" Text="Search" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAddDeptUser" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>


                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >
                    <asp:Button ID="btnRmvDeptMem" runat="server" Text="Remove" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddDeptUser" runat="server" Text="Add" />
                </td>

            </tr>

        </table>
```

[Full code for Departments.aspx](http://pastebin.com/uVVt44Zb)

Comment: Where is this dropdownlist, you haven't shown it?

Comment: And why do you query the id of the `department_id` from the database according to the `department_name` of the dropdownlist's `SelectedItem`? You just have to set the [`DataValueField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield.asp) to your id-field, then the value is the id and the text(what is displayed) is the name.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Updated the question with drop down code.

Comment: please provide a complete sample code. we can't figure where is the HTML part of the dropdownlist and where it is being bound!

Comment: @MuhammadOmar You're right. Sorry. Updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Brian: You have edited the question but it's still not clear where the `DropDownList` is located. Is it in this page, is in the UpdatePanel, in another UpdatePanel, in this page, in a MasterPage in a different UserControl, .....?

Comment: @TimSchmelter No, it's located 'alone'. Not in the UpdatePanel2 and not in the table that contains the ListBox. I have re-edited with that part of the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the `UpdatePanel` immediately when the user selects an item in the `DropDownList` you have to set it's  [`AutoPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback.aspx) property to `"True"`(default is `false`):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpDepartments" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" 
    AutoPostack="True" DataTextField="department_name" DataValueField="department_name">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: @TimeSchmelter Ahh nevermind. I had to change it from the GUI.

Comment: Altough it is updating, the page is throwing me an error (it opens up some page in C# code whenever I try to changed selected value of DropDown)

Answer (score 1):

try this...
Change this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
```

with

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

Comment: Then you have to call `UpdatePanel2.Update()` from codebehind manually. However, that is not the reason since he has defined an `AsyncPostBackTrigger`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter pls check this like second option of conditional update.....
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx